# Managing organization structure and permissions with keycloak

Tags: java, oauth, authorization, keycloak

We have a multi-tenant (used by multiple organizations) application in Java Spring Boot. We have to implement authentication as well as authorization in such a way that;

1. There can be multiple users in an organization and a user can also be part of multiple organizations.
2. At a time user can view data of only one organization but he can simply switch between organizations.
3. In an organization, there can be multiple teams.
4. A user can have different level of access/permissions for each team. Like maybe a user A is manager of team 1 and same time he can be member of team 2 etc.

We are planning to use keycloak for IAM. So the question is, either this type of access management will be possible to achieve in keycloak or we have to manage these permissions on database level in code? And for multi-tenancy, a separate realm for each tenant will be good or we should go for single realm and multiple groups?

Looking for expert opinions.

Comment: We have very similar requirements and are about to adopt keycloak for the same purpose. Can you share the solution you ended for (1) implementing multitenancy in keycloak (per realm/groups/other) (2) managing user access right/permissions/roles?